# unexpected output from hashMap

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

This is a challenge problem from codewars.com. I am trying to reduce the number of times the inner loop is accessed by using a hashMap to help me avoid repeating characters. However, my logic since to fail at some point, could you please give me a heads up as to where i am messing up? 
Thanks 
Below is the challenge description:
The goal of this exercise is to convert a string to a new string where each character in the new string is '(' if that character appears only once in the original string, or ')' if that character appears more than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when determining if a character is a duplicate.

Examples:
"din" => "((("
  --and-- "recede" => "()()()"

```
 public class DuplicateEncoder {
static String encode(String word){
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
      int count;  //counter for # time character is preset
      int i = 0; 
      String answer = ""; 

      for(int j = 0; j <= word.length() -1; j++)
      {
          count = 0;
          //only allows input if the key is not present in the hashmap
        if( !(map.containsKey(word.charAt(j)) ) )
        {
             // should count the time the character is present.
            //there apprears to be a bug in here
            for( i = j ; i < word.length() -1 ; i++)
              {

                if(  (word.charAt(j))  == word.charAt(i)  ) count++;        

              }
        }

        map.put( word.charAt(j), count); // 

      }
```

//System.out.println(map.keySet());
//System.out.println(map.values());

```
      for(i = 0; i <=  word.length() -1; i++)
      {
          if(map.get(word.charAt(i)) <= 1) 
          {
              answer += "(";
          }
          else{
              answer += ")";
          }

      }

        return answer;
      }

public static void main(String ...args)
{
    System.out.println(encode("recede"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

As @Hugo suggested you don't need the inner loop. It is better to put each character in the map adjusting the number of occurrence.
In addition you may use [Java Stream API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) and [`java.lang.StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to make the code better:

```
  public static String encode(String word) {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    word.chars().forEach(character -> map.put(character, map.getOrDefault(character, 0) + 1));

    final StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    word.chars().forEach(value -> answer.append(map.get(value) > 1 ? ')' : '('));
    return answer.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need one loop (in *pseudo  code* because I'm typing in my cell phone - sorry):

```
for (each character in word)
    if (character not in map)
        map.put(character, 1)
    else
        map.put(character, map.get(character) +1)
```

With this, the map will contain the number of times each character appears in `word`

Comment: your approach works beautifully, I did made some changes use map.replace(character, ++count))

Comment: @JoseGonzalez yes, it's another way of doing it as well